# How to make difference of first value and last value based on other column value condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have one dataframe with Column A and Column B. I want to divide dataframe in piece based on Column B , if value is less than 0 until its not goes up to 0 , for this piece check if column A piece start value is greater than 5 then in result dataframe column value_down count 1, and other column in result C is difference if first value of piece minus last value of piece divided by 2300... The same thing need to do when value of column B.

Here is input data

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[0.15,2.39,0.15,5.3,5.36,5.99,6.45,6.54,3.68,3.83,3.44,0.84,0.67,2.97,2.98,5.53,6.55,3.71,1.13,0.15,0.24,2.39,3.48,4.97,5.09,6.44,6.24,0.07,0.07,0.04,0.1,0.07,5.64,0.07,0.04],'B':[0,-1203,-159,-35,0,0,0,0,205,-11,0,0,0,-145,-14,-12,0,182,-11,0,-145,0,-14,0,0,-12,0,1374,0,-613,243,370,-1374,761,0]})
```

output

```
df_out= pd.DataFrame({'Value_down':[4],'Value_down_piece_diff':[-0.607,-0.079,-0.079,-0.59],'Value_up':[4],'Value_up_piece_diff':[0.089,0.079,0.59,0.33]})
```

Value_down_piece_diff formula= piece first value- last value /2300

Comment: I got for second `df` - `ValueError: arrays must all be same length`

Comment: @ yes, you can repeat same number 4 for making same length,,, actually this 4 number represent for value down have 4 pieces in dataframe

Comment: `for this piece check if column A piece start value is greater than 5` - in sample data all data start by `5`, can you explain more?

Comment: in piece if any one value of column A is greater than 2 , then consider this piece , otherwise ignore piece

Comment: I am confused, so there are 2 groups less like `2` - `row 20` and `row 27`, why is expected output `4` down and 4 up? Not understand it.

Comment: Output data are from input? Or it is something else?

Comment: in group if any one value is greater than 2 is ok, if all values less than 2 then ignore piece

Comment: Ok, so rows `20,27` are ignored, can you explain `4 up, 4 down` ? Becuse there are 9 groups, subtract 2 get 7 groups.

Comment: @ jezrael    you are right , there are 7 groups

Comment: I add part solution, can you explain more what is necessary do in next step?

Comment: in groups you ignored rows with value zero ,please do not ignore rows with value zero , because after getting groups we need operation to make difference of first value of piece-last value of piece divided by 2300

Comment: OK, so what should be next step after `df = df[~mask]`?

Comment: on your email ID i am sending you excel sheet , this excel can explain more , please check